# Roots of a polynomial in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let p (x) an m-degree polynomial with m distinct real roots. Prove that the roots of p '(x) are real and
different.
TIP: Try Rolle's theorem

Comment: What have you try?

Comment: @Camille Got it. Thanks to you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polynomial $p(x)$ can be expressed as $p(x) = a(x - x_1) \dots (x-x_m)$ for constant $a$ and distinct roots $x_1,\dots,x_m$.

It is easy to see by taking the derivative $p'(x)$ that none of the roots of $p(x)$ are stationary points. To see this just substitute $x_1, \dots, x_n$ respectively. All terms of $p'(x)$ will reduce to zero except one term, which is non-zero by distinctness of all $x_i$.

By extreme value theorem there must exist (non-zero) minima or maxima between each pair of roots, and there are $m-1$ such pairs. Then at these minima or maxima, the derivative is 0, so $p'(x) = 0$. This establishes that the number of real roots of $p'(x) \geq m-1$.

But $p'(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $m-1$, so it can have at most $m-1$ roots. So $p'(x)$ has precisely $m-1$ real roots. Distinctness follows from the fact that each root is found in the interval $(x_i, x_{i+1})$ for $i = 1,\dots,m-1$, since each of these intervals must contain exactly one root, there are $m-1$ of them, and they are all disjoint.